# Disk Store Files (*.drf, *.crf, *.krf) files not getting deleted after reaching "max-oplog-size" - Pivotal Gemfire

Tags: gemfire

I have one Disk store with the following attributes:

```
<disk-store name="DATA" compaction-threshold="40" auto-compact="true" max-oplog-size="512" queue-size="10000">

<disk-dirs>

<disk-dir>/storage/data/</disk-dir>

</disk-dirs>

</disk-store>
```

I am adding data to the following region:

```
<region-attributes id="testRegionAttrib" concurrency-checks-enabled="true" statistics-enabled="true" initial-capacity="10000"

data-policy="persistent-replicate" scope="distributed-ack" disk-store-name="DATA">

<entry-time-to-live>

<expiration-attributes timeout="500"/>

</entry-time-to-live>

</region-attributes>

<region-attributes id="rLockAttrib" data-policy="replicate" scope="global"/>


<region name="testRegion" refid="testRegionAttrib">

<index name="idPkIndex">

<primary-key field="id" />

</index>

</region>
```

I can see some of the BACKUPDATA files getting deleted intially after a time period of 500 seconds as mentioned in the region-attribute TTL attribute. However, after the time of 500 seconds has reached, the other files don't get deleted that were created after the 500 second period.

I would like to achieve so that any a full BACKUPDATA file (1MB in this case) gets deleted after the TTL period.

I have attached before and after screenshots to give more clarity.
[image: Before]

[image: After]

Diskstore analysis:

````
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 0M Jan 13 16:06 DRLK_IFDATA.lk
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:12 BACKUPDATA_1.drf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:12 BACKUPDATA_1.crf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:12 BACKUPDATA_1.krf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:12 BACKUPDATA_2.drf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:12 BACKUPDATA_2.crf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:12 BACKUPDATA_2.krf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:12 BACKUPDATA_3.crf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:12 BACKUPDATA_3.drf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:12 BACKUPDATA_3.krf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:12 BACKUPDATA_4.drf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:12 BACKUPDATA_4.crf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:12 BACKUPDATA_4.krf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:12 BACKUPDATA_5.crf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:12 BACKUPDATA_5.drf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:12 BACKUPDATA_5.krf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:12 BACKUPDATA_6.drf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:12 BACKUPDATA_6.crf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:12 BACKUPDATA_6.krf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:12 BACKUPDATA_7.crf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:12 BACKUPDATA_7.drf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:12 BACKUPDATA_7.krf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:12 BACKUPDATA_8.drf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:12 BACKUPDATA_8.crf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:12 BACKUPDATA_8.krf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:12 BACKUPDATA_9.drf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:12 BACKUPDATA_9.crf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:12 BACKUPDATA_9.krf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:12 BACKUPDATA_10.drf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:12 BACKUPDATA_10.crf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:12 BACKUPDATA_10.krf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:12 BACKUPDATA_11.drf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:12 BACKUPDATA_11.crf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:12 BACKUPDATA_11.krf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:12 BACKUPDATA_12.crf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:12 BACKUPDATA_12.drf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:12 BACKUPDATA_12.krf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:12 BACKUPDATA_13.drf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:12 BACKUPDATA_13.crf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:12 BACKUPDATA_13.krf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:12 BACKUPDATA_14.drf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:12 BACKUPDATA_14.crf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:12 BACKUPDATA_14.krf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:12 BACKUPDATA_15.drf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:12 BACKUPDATA_15.crf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:12 BACKUPDATA_15.krf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:12 BACKUPDATA_16.drf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:12 BACKUPDATA_16.crf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:12 BACKUPDATA_16.krf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:12 BACKUPDATA_17.crf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:12 BACKUPDATA_17.drf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:12 BACKUPDATA_17.krf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:13 BACKUPDATA_18.drf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:13 BACKUPDATA_18.crf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:13 BACKUPDATA_18.krf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:13 BACKUPDATA_19.crf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:13 BACKUPDATA_19.drf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:13 BACKUPDATA_19.krf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:13 BACKUPDATA_20.crf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:13 BACKUPDATA_20.drf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:13 BACKUPDATA_20.krf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:13 BACKUPDATA_21.drf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:13 BACKUPDATA_21.crf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:13 BACKUPDATA_21.krf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:13 BACKUPDATA_23.drf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:13 BACKUPDATA_22.drf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:13 BACKUPDATA_22.crf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:13 BACKUPDATA.if
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:13 BACKUPDATA_22.krf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:13 BACKUPDATA_23.crf

After TTL period:
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 0M Jan 13 16:06 DRLK_IFDATA.lk
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:21 BACKUPDATA_23.drf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:21 BACKUPDATA_23.crf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:21 BACKUPDATA_23.krf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:21 BACKUPDATA_24.drf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:21 BACKUPDATA_24.crf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:21 BACKUPDATA_24.krf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:21 BACKUPDATA_25.drf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:21 BACKUPDATA_25.crf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:21 BACKUPDATA_25.krf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:21 BACKUPDATA_26.drf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:21 BACKUPDATA_26.crf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:21 BACKUPDATA_26.krf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:21 BACKUPDATA_27.krf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:21 BACKUPDATA_27.drf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:21 BACKUPDATA_27.crf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:21 BACKUPDATA_28.drf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:21 BACKUPDATA_28.crf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:21 BACKUPDATA_28.krf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:21 BACKUPDATA_29.drf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:21 BACKUPDATA_29.crf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:21 BACKUPDATA_29.krf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:21 BACKUPDATA_30.drf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:21 BACKUPDATA_30.crf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:21 BACKUPDATA_30.krf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:21 BACKUPDATA_32.drf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:21 BACKUPDATA_31.drf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:21 BACKUPDATA_31.crf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:21 BACKUPDATA.if
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:21 BACKUPDATA_31.krf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:21 BACKUPDATA_32.crf

After sending another batch of data:
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 0M Jan 13 16:06 DRLK_IFDATA.lk
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:21 BACKUPDATA_23.drf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:21 BACKUPDATA_23.crf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:21 BACKUPDATA_23.krf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:21 BACKUPDATA_24.drf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:21 BACKUPDATA_24.crf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:21 BACKUPDATA_24.krf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:21 BACKUPDATA_25.drf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:21 BACKUPDATA_25.crf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:21 BACKUPDATA_25.krf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:21 BACKUPDATA_26.drf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:21 BACKUPDATA_26.crf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:21 BACKUPDATA_26.krf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:21 BACKUPDATA_27.krf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:21 BACKUPDATA_27.drf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:21 BACKUPDATA_27.crf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:21 BACKUPDATA_28.drf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:21 BACKUPDATA_28.crf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:21 BACKUPDATA_28.krf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:21 BACKUPDATA_29.drf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:21 BACKUPDATA_29.crf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:21 BACKUPDATA_29.krf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:21 BACKUPDATA_30.drf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:21 BACKUPDATA_30.crf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:21 BACKUPDATA_30.krf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:21 BACKUPDATA_31.drf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:21 BACKUPDATA_31.crf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:21 BACKUPDATA_31.krf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:57 BACKUPDATA_32.drf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:57 BACKUPDATA_32.crf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:57 BACKUPDATA_32.krf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:58 BACKUPDATA_33.drf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:58 BACKUPDATA_33.crf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:58 BACKUPDATA_33.krf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:58 BACKUPDATA_34.drf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:58 BACKUPDATA_34.crf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:58 BACKUPDATA_34.krf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:58 BACKUPDATA_35.drf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:58 BACKUPDATA_35.crf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:58 BACKUPDATA_35.krf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:58 BACKUPDATA_36.drf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:58 BACKUPDATA_36.crf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:58 BACKUPDATA_36.krf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:58 BACKUPDATA_37.drf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:58 BACKUPDATA_37.crf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:58 BACKUPDATA_37.krf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:58 BACKUPDATA_38.krf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:58 BACKUPDATA_38.drf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:58 BACKUPDATA_38.crf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:58 BACKUPDATA_39.drf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:58 BACKUPDATA_39.crf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:58 BACKUPDATA_39.krf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:58 BACKUPDATA_40.drf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:58 BACKUPDATA_40.crf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:58 BACKUPDATA_40.krf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:58 BACKUPDATA_41.drf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:58 BACKUPDATA_41.crf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:58 BACKUPDATA_41.krf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:58 BACKUPDATA_42.drf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:58 BACKUPDATA_42.crf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:58 BACKUPDATA_42.krf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:58 BACKUPDATA_43.krf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:58 BACKUPDATA_43.drf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:58 BACKUPDATA_43.crf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:58 BACKUPDATA_44.drf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:58 BACKUPDATA_44.crf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:58 BACKUPDATA_44.krf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:58 BACKUPDATA_45.drf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:58 BACKUPDATA_45.crf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:58 BACKUPDATA_45.krf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:58 BACKUPDATA_46.drf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:58 BACKUPDATA_46.crf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:58 BACKUPDATA_46.krf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:58 BACKUPDATA_47.drf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:58 BACKUPDATA_47.crf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:58 BACKUPDATA_47.krf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:58 BACKUPDATA_48.drf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:58 BACKUPDATA_48.crf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:58 BACKUPDATA_48.krf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:58 BACKUPDATA_49.drf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:58 BACKUPDATA_49.crf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:58 BACKUPDATA_49.krf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:58 BACKUPDATA_50.drf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:58 BACKUPDATA_50.crf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:58 BACKUPDATA_50.krf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:58 BACKUPDATA_52.drf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:58 BACKUPDATA_52.crf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:58 BACKUPDATA_51.drf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:58 BACKUPDATA_51.crf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:58 BACKUPDATA.if
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:58 BACKUPDATA_51.krf

After TTL after sending the next batch:
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 0M Jan 13 16:06 DRLK_IFDATA.lk
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:21 BACKUPDATA_23.drf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:21 BACKUPDATA_23.crf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:21 BACKUPDATA_23.krf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:21 BACKUPDATA_24.drf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:21 BACKUPDATA_24.crf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:21 BACKUPDATA_24.krf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:21 BACKUPDATA_25.drf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:21 BACKUPDATA_25.crf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:21 BACKUPDATA_25.krf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:21 BACKUPDATA_26.drf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:21 BACKUPDATA_26.crf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:21 BACKUPDATA_26.krf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:21 BACKUPDATA_27.krf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:21 BACKUPDATA_27.drf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:21 BACKUPDATA_27.crf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:21 BACKUPDATA_28.drf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:21 BACKUPDATA_28.crf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:21 BACKUPDATA_28.krf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:21 BACKUPDATA_29.drf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:21 BACKUPDATA_29.crf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:21 BACKUPDATA_29.krf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:21 BACKUPDATA_30.drf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:21 BACKUPDATA_30.crf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:21 BACKUPDATA_30.krf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:21 BACKUPDATA_31.drf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:21 BACKUPDATA_31.crf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 16:21 BACKUPDATA_31.krf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 17:06 BACKUPDATA_52.drf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 17:06 BACKUPDATA_52.crf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 17:06 BACKUPDATA_52.krf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 17:06 BACKUPDATA_53.drf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 17:06 BACKUPDATA_53.crf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 17:06 BACKUPDATA_53.krf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 17:06 BACKUPDATA_54.drf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 17:06 BACKUPDATA_54.crf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 17:06 BACKUPDATA_54.krf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 17:06 BACKUPDATA_55.drf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 17:06 BACKUPDATA_55.crf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 17:06 BACKUPDATA_55.krf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 17:06 BACKUPDATA_56.drf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 17:06 BACKUPDATA_56.crf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 17:06 BACKUPDATA_56.krf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 17:06 BACKUPDATA_57.drf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 17:06 BACKUPDATA_57.crf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 17:06 BACKUPDATA_57.krf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 17:06 BACKUPDATA_59.drf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 17:06 BACKUPDATA_58.drf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 17:06 BACKUPDATA_58.crf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 17:06 BACKUPDATA_58.krf
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 17:06 BACKUPDATA.if
-rw-r--r-- 1 a_cdtcs a_cdtcs 1M Jan 13 17:06 BACKUPDATA_59.crf```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The TTL on the region applies to the region entries themselves. So after 500 seconds your entries will not be visible to region.get, for example.

However, that TTL does not apply directly to the disk store files. Region entries will be marked as deleted in the disk store files, and as more entries get deleted compaction will happen and reclaim space on disk, but that doesn't mean all of the files will go away.

In particular, Geode keeps *tombstones* for deleted/expired entries for conflict resolution purposes for a period of time, so simply creating and deleting all of your data will not necessarily result in 0 disk space used, or at least not right away.

Comment: Yes you are right, I understood that from my analysis. So there is no way to ensure that disk store files can get deleted after being full for a certain period.

Can you please elaborate more on the “as more entries get deleted compaction will happen and reclaim space on disk”. 
When I add more data into the region I can see the existing full disk store files getting deleted and more disk store files being created. Is this supporting with the concept you stated above?

Comment: Yes. Compaction is asynchronous. When file has more garbage than the compaction threshold it will be eligible to be deleted immediately. Data in the file becomes garbage by updating or destroying entries. However, destroys themselves are actually recorded as tombstones (not garbage), so they will still take some space until the tombstones expire.

Comment: Hi I have done analysis and fewof the diskstore file doesn't get deleted after sending more batches of data. I have added my analysis in the original post. I can see the files BACKUPDATA_23 to BACKUPDATA_31 haven't got deleted even though many new diskstore files were created.